# How to set inline css width using model values in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

In my case I pass data from controller to view using ViewBag.data and it binds correctly. Now what I want is to set the CSS width value. This is part of my view code.

```
  @foreach(var rat in @ViewBag.reviewRating)
  {
      <div class="Traveler-ratingsLine">
           <div class="Traveler-ratingsText">Excellent</div>
           <div class="Traveler-ratingsBar">
                 <div style="width: 100px" class="Traveler-ratingsBkg">
                      <div style="width: 32px;" class="Traveler-ratingsImg"></div>
                 </div>
           </div>
           <div class="Traveler-ratingsTextGreen">@rat.excellent</div>
     </div>
 }
```

So what I want to know is, is it possible to do something like this:

```
<div style="width: (@rat.someval)px;" class="Traveler-ratingsImg"></div>
```

I want to set the integer value from the controller like this for the CSS width.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do it like this-

```
<div style="width: @(rat.someval+"px")" class="Traveler-ratingsImg"></div>
```

see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zc6N9q)